# Discover if calendar room (resource) is bookable through the Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk

In GSuite, you can set a room (resource) to be viewable by a user but not bookable.

This will show up as a crossed out (unavailable) room - see screenshot below.

How can you find out if a room is bookable by me through the Google APIs? There doesn't appear to be anything in the calendar resource that contains this information (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/resources.calendars#CalendarResource).

I've also tried to put in the `resourceEmail` of the room as the `calendarId` in the ACL endpoint here, but non-admins don't have access to those ACLs so it isn't useful in discovering if I'm able to book a room or not.

[image: Non-bookable room]

Comment: could you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating your scenario and the result I got was, in Google API, there was **NO** parameter that mentions if the resource is BOOKABLE or not.

To view the details of the resource in Google API, you can use "my_customer" in the **customer** field as an alias of your account's customer ID(also indicated in the documentation at this link: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/resources.calendars/get#http-request)
[image]

Next, indicate the **Resource id** of your resource in the **calendarResourceId** field.

After clicking the EXECUTE button, you will get the following parameters with the details of your resource next to it:

200:

```
{
  "kind": *string*,
  "etags": *string*,
  "resourceId": *string*,
  "resourceName": *string*,
  "generatedResourceName": *string*,
  "resourceType": *string*,
  "resourceEmail": *string*,
  "capacity": *integer*,
  "resourceCategory": *string*
}
```

#### Feature Request filed in Issue Tracker:

- [Discover calendar room (resource) is bookable](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174576234)

Comment: Thanks! Yes this is what I had found as well. As noted I filed a feature request in the issue tracker.

Comment: Hi @VarunSingh! Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it was helpful to you. Thank you.